# Scheduler algorithm that fill remaning hours to work

Tags: c#, algorithm, scheduler

I need to generate all possible values to a scheduler who works like this:
Some hours of the week can be already chosen. 
The week of work is defined by the following pattern "???????" question marks can be replaced.
Given a maximum of hours, I need to replace the question marks with digits so that the sum of the scheduled hours match the hours need to work in a week returning a string array with all possible schedules, ordered lexicographically.

Example:
pattern = "08??840", 
required_week_hours= 24

In this example, there are only 4 hours left to work.

calling this:

```
function List<String> GenerateScheduler(int workHours, int dayHours, string pattern){}

    public static void Main(){
     GenerateScheduler(24, 4, "08??840");
    }
```

This would return the following list of strings:

0804840
0813840
.......
.......
0840840

I'm not very familiar with algorithms, which one I could use to solve this problem?

Comment: You will need to write your own algorithm.

Comment: "0812840" => That doesn't quite satisfy required_week_hours right ? according to your description it should sum to 24 ?

Comment: `function List<String> GenerateScheduler(int workHours, int dayHours, string pattern){}` - are you sure this is C#?

Comment: Also, what you have try so far?

Comment: You are right @AnuViswan. It was a typo, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem where you have to generate all permutations of a list of a certain amount of numbers that sum up to a certain number. First, you need to sum up the hours you already know. Then you need to count up the number of `?` aka the number of shifts/days you do not know about. Using these parameters, this is what the solution will look like,

```
public List<string> GenerateScheduler(int workHours, int dayHours, string pattern){
    int remainingSum = workHours;
    int unknownCount = 0;
    // first iterate through the pattern to know how many ? characters there are
    // as well as the number of hours remaining
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++) {
        if (pattern[i] == '?') {
            unknownCount++;
        }
        else {
            remainingSum -= pattern[i] - '0';
        }
    }
    List<List<int>> permutations = new List<List<int>>();
    // get all the lists of work shifts that sum to the remaining number of hours
    // the number of work shifts in each list is the number of ? characters in pattern
    GeneratePermutations(permutations, workHours, unknownCount); 

    // after getting all the permutations, we need to iterate through the pattern
    // for each permutation to construct a list of schedules to return
    List<string> schedules = new List<string>();
    foreach (List<int> permutation in permutation) {
        StringBuilder newSchedule = new StringBuilder();
        int permCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length(); i++) {
            if (pattern[i] == '?') {
                newSchedule.Append(permutation[permCount]);
                permCount++;
            }
            else {
                newSchedule.Append(pattern[i]);
            }
        }
        schedules.Add(newSchedule.ToString());
    }
    return schedules;
}

public void GeneratePermutations(List<List<int>> permutations, int workHours, int unknownCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= workHours; i++) {
        List<int> permutation = new List<int>();
        permutation.Add(i);
        GeneratePermuationsHelper(permutations, permutation, workHours - i, unknownCount - 1); 
    }
}

public void GeneratePermutationsHelper(List<List<int>> permutations, List<int> permutation, int remainingHours, int remainingShifts){
    if (remainingShifts == 0 && remainingHours == 0) {
        permutations.Add(permutation);
        return;
    }
    if (remainingHours <= 0 || remainingShifts <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= remainingHours; i++) {
        List<int> newPermutation = new List<int>(permutation);
        newPermutation.Add(i);
        GeneratePermutationsHelper(permutations, newPermutation, remainingHours - i, remainingShifts - 1);
    }     
}
```

This can be a lot to digest so I will briefly go over how the permutation recursive helper function works. The parameters go as follows:

- a list containing all the permutations
- the current permutation being examined
- the remaining number of hours needed to reach the total work hour count
- the number of remaining shifts (basically number of '?' - permutation.Count)

First, we check to see if the current permutation meets the criteria that the total of its work hours equals the amount of hours remaining needed to complete the pattern and the number of shifts in the permutation equals the number of question marks in the pattern. If it does, then we add this permutation to the list of permutations. If it doesn't, we check to see if the total amount of work hours surpasses the amount of hours remaining or if the number of shifts has reached the number of question marks in the pattern. If so, then the permutation is not added. However, if we can still add more shifts, we will run a loop from i = 0 to remainingHours and make a copy of the permutation while adding i to this copied list in each iteration of the loop. Then, we will adjust the remaining hours and remaining shifts accordingly before calling the helper function recursively with the copied permutation.

Lastly, we can use these permutations to create a list of new schedules, replacing the ? characters in the pattern with the numbers from each permutation.

Answer (score 0):

As per OP, you already know the remaining hours, which I assume is given by the parameter dayHours. So, if you were to break down the problem further, you would need to replace '?' characters with numbers so that, sum of new character(number) is equal to remaining hours(dayHours).

You can do the following.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GenerateScheduler(int totalHours,int remainingHours,string replacementString)
{
    var numberOfPlaces = replacementString.Count(x => x == '?');
    var minValue = remainingHours;
    var maxValue = remainingHours * Math.Pow(10,numberOfPlaces-1);
    var combinations = Enumerable.Range(remainingHours,(int)maxValue)
            .Where(x=> SumOfDigit(x) == remainingHours).Select(x=>x.ToString().PadLeft(numberOfPlaces,'0').ToCharArray());

    foreach(var item in combinations)
    {
        var i = 0;
        yield return Regex.Replace(replacementString, "[?]", (m) => {return item[i++].ToString(); });
    }
}

double SumOfDigit(int value)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        int remainder;
        value = Math.DivRem(value, 10, out remainder);
        sum += remainder;
    }
    return sum;
}
```